# Why does my npm request module work in tonicdev but not in my Node app in OpenShift cloud?

Tags: node.js, express, openshift, node-request

I have a Node Express app that runs with no problems on the OpenShift cloud. It accepts router.post and router.get just fine. But I want the OpenShift app to also post some data to a Raspberry Pi which is also running a Node and Express app. To accomplish this, on the OpenShift app, I am using the Node npm request module. When I run it in the Node dev space at http://tonicdev.com, it works just fine. It sends its JSON data to the RPi and the Pi accepts and processes it.

[image]

But when I run the exact same request code in the node app in the OpenShift cloud it crashes with an EACCES error.  Note that I am using the request-debug module which displays the request module headers immediately before the crash. They are as expected to be.

[image]

What in the devil is going on in the OpenShift environment that is changing the request module's execution causing it to crash, and how can I address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift Online currently has a whitelist of acceptable outbound ports, and port 3000 is probably not in the list. We can add ports to the list, but typically we only do this for well-known service ports.  Can you run the remote service on a different port (such as 80 or 8080)?

Comment: I sure can try it. I'm in full control of the Raspberry Pi. Do you have a link available where I can check on acceptable ports so I can shortcut this problem? I have been out of commission for days. I will try 8080 and get back.